# Can't compile when using protocol extension and @objc

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-protocols

I can't get the following code to compile and I'm not sure why. I've simplified it down to this for the sake of readability.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {

    func someMethod() -> String
}

extension MyProtocol {

    func someMethod() -> String {
        return "Foo"
    }
}

@objc class MyClass: NSObject, MyProtocol {

}

let obj: MyProtocol = MyClass()
obj.someMethod()
```

What is strange is if I declare obj to be of type MyClass like so -

```
let obj: MyClass = MyClass()
```

It works fine. It also works if I remove the @objc from the protocol definition. Instances of MyClass will be used by Objective-C, so I need to use @objc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Same as the duplicate-linked question. Protocol extension are not compatible with Objective-C, so you can't feed one into the Objective-C world by making MyClass an NSObject as you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah ok, great. Thanks Matt!

Comment: No problem. You have described very well the bounding conditions under which this is legal (i.e. the extended protocol and the adopting class can't _both_ be Objective-C); upvoted for that.